# Aqua data studio return wrong count affected rows

Tags: jdbc, jconnect, aqua-data-studio

I connected to Sybase Ase 15.0.3 with Aqua Data Studio.
Data base has drive version:

installjdbc ----    jConnect (TM) for JDBC(TM)/7.00(Build 26502)/P/EBF17821/JDK16/Tue Apr  6 11:59:33 2010

ADS has driver:

jConnect (TM) for JDBC(TM)/16.0 PL01 N-OFF (Build 27031)/P/EBF22531/JDK 1.6.0/jdbcmain/OPT/Thu Mar 20 11:14:13 PDT 2014

When I try to update - incorrect count of affected rows returns. For example, updated 1 but affected rows returned 3. I have installed jdk1.8 and jre 1.8

What is causing this?

Comment: Depends on the driver and database system, but maybe a trigger fired that inserted two rows in other tables. Some database system will count all those modifications. Why do you even care about this?

Comment: Mark, because I need to know exact amount of updated/inserted/deleted rows. Thanks for response.

Comment: Mark, you was right. For table exist switched trigger, which for every update - was updating other table (two times). I turned off it. And row count became proper. Thank you very much. So, now exist other question - how to change count of affected rows to show only changed rows (not affected rows in all database) in current table.